# Any way to see the number of lines in a file without opening the file?

Tags: shell, text-files, tcsh

I have a rather large text file (~45MB) and I want to know how many lines total it has. Since the file is so large, it takes too long to open with a text editor and check manually that way.  I am wondering if there is a shell command/shell script (I'd prefer a tcsh answer since that's what I use) or any other way to "quickly" (meaning, more quickly than opening the file and checking out the end) determine how many lines the text file has?

I am in a *nix environment.

Comment: what about `wc -l file.txt`? Are you in a *nix environment, I suppose.

Comment: I am and added that to my question.

Comment: Are you intersted in the EXACT number or is a rough estimate fine? You could divide filesize by average line lenght....for that number you don't have to touch the file....

Comment: That could work as well.  But how would I determine the average line length?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
wc -l filename
```

It won't be fast, since it has to read the entire file to count the lines. But there's no other way, since Unix doesn't keep track of that anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Use `wc` (word count, which has a "lines" mode):

```
LINES=`wc -l file.txt`
echo $LINES
```

Comment: That's not tcsh variable assignment syntax.

Comment: Been a long while since I used tcsh. but the basic concept works anyways.